# geometric objects in quiver variety corresponding to short exact sequences

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quivers, quiver-varieties

I was studying quiver variety and known that representations of a quiver correspond to points in the corresponding quiver variety. So if give you a fixed triple representations $(M_1,M_2,M_3)$, I was just wondering is there a geometric object inside quiver variety that corresponds to a short exact sequences between $(M_1,M_2,M_3)$.

Comment: You might want to check out Hall algebra - it's an algebra on equivalence classes of quiver representations with a product encoded in all possible extensions. It has some geometric meaning as explained, for example, [here](https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/hall-algebras-are-grothendieck-groups/#more-3988).